# How can I reduce the size of an array argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a template function, bar, that takes a reference to an array as a parameter.  I'd like to take the argument and pass it to another function, but only after reducing the size of the array by one, and skipping past the first element of the array.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{
  std::cout << sizeof(t) << std::endl;
  std::cout << t[0] << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void bar(const T& t)
{
  std::cout << sizeof(t) << std::endl;
  std::cout << t[0] << std::endl;
  foo(t); // Magic is desired here!
}

int main()
{
  char array[] = "ABCD";
  bar(array);
}
```

The above prints out:

```
5
A
5
A
```

I'd like it to print out:

```
5
A
4
B
```

Comment: is copying the array ok?

Comment: Since you use pointers those arrays don't have a size, and sizeof(pointer) just returns 4 or 8 depending on the system.

Comment: Njol is right. Your sizeof(pointer) will just return the size of a pointer on your system. If you still want to pass a reduced array size then you can just pass foo(t+1) or foo(&t[1]) if that's clearer to you.

Comment: No, those arrays are passed **by reference** and thus are not converted to a pointer. The type of `t` in the function will be an array type, not a pointer type, and thus `sizeof` will get you the size of the array, not of the pointer. However, the `&t[1]` trick for the forwarding call won't work, since *then* you have a pointer, not an array.

Comment: For those who don't believe this: http://ideone.com/RyVHps It will actually print `5` (and I doubt that any pointer type is 5 bytes large).

Comment: They are not pointers! Try with c++11 and typeinfo(t).name()

Comment: @user3125280, I'd really rather not copy the array because I want things to be efficient.  If I wanted to copy the array I could declare an array of sizeof(T)-1, and then copy things into that.

Comment: For those who wonder why this works: it's the reference which does the magic here. If the parameter had type `T`, it would be a pointer, because arrays can't be passed by value and the standard says that in this case it's only a pointer to the first element (also if you explicitly write `char[]` in the signature, it's actually `char*`) See here: http://ideone.com/qfQ8nK

Comment: @razeh I hope you know that `sizeof(t)` (or `sizeof(T)`) will not give you the number of elements in the array but the total *memory size* of the array, so you want `sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])`.

Comment: @razeh i try to solve this with decltype but the compiler complains about array of references

Comment: @leemes, yes, good point.  I'm actually rather fond of the trick posted at https://coderwall.com/p/nb9ngq

Comment: @razeh i gave an answer that doesn't need two template parameters, and uses reference to array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with *two* template parameters, one for the array type and one for the size of the array.

```
template <typename T, int N>
void bar(const T (&t)[N])
{
    // ...
    foo(reinterpret_cast<const T(&)[N-1]>(t[1]));
}
```

Comment: I guess you forgot a `&` before the `t[1]`

Comment: @leemes, no that would convert it to a pointer. I want a reference.

Comment: I could do it with two, but if I do it with one I'm not repeating myself and can't make a mistake.

Comment: Right, I see. Sorry ;)

Comment: @razeh: you don't have to supply the size parameter (`N` in Mark's code above) manually when you use the template - the compiler works it out when matching - so there's no new risk once you've got the `bar` template itself written correctly.

Comment: Extending on Tony D's comment: It's also more typesafe. The signature already tells you the type constraints which the function's body requires. In the original code, the compiler could match `T` with any type (when looking at the signature), deferring compilation error to when the body is being compiled. In Mark Ransom's solution, during template type deduction the function is not accepted as a candidate, giving a nice error message when used with incorrect types. This very simple trick of constraining template types should be used whenever possible, not only whenever there is no other way.

Comment: Why are you casting the first element of t instead of casting t itself?

Comment: @Tony D, good point!  But when I try to compile this with clang, I get: error: 't' declared as array of references of type 'const T &'
void bar(const T& t[N])

Comment: @razeh, Mark, It's a small typo. It should be `const T(&t)[N]`. See the spiral rule for reading types.

Comment: @razeh When applying chris' fix, it compiles and works as expected: http://ideone.com/stWQ4s

Comment: @chris, thanks for catching that. How could I get it right in the cast but wrong in the signature?

Comment: the reliance on reinterpret_cast (as in my answer, and i believe any possible answer) means that this solution is not casting at compile time, as there are possible errors if foo deletes its array,etc (i think)

Comment: @Casey, it's not the first element, it's the second. You need to do that to remove the first element from the array.

Comment: @user3125280 it's most definitely casting at compile time. The only cast that doesn't is `dynamic_cast`. You can't delete an array, only a pointer, although I think it would be a run-time error rather than a compile-time error due to the natural decay of arrays to pointers.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah sorry - i meant that i think this still can't be used to process strings at compile time. it works obviously, for its purpose - i wrote a working one too - but they don't have TMP potential, do they?

Comment: @user3125280: on the off-chance you're more familiar with "C" casts, it may help to think of `reinterpret_cast<T>(v)` as being similar to `*(T*)&v` - it's just telling the compiler that - for the purposes of whatever operation's performed on the returned value - to treat the memory from `v` as if it contained a different type.  The cast itself doesn't require any runtime behaviour or inspection of the memory, and the behaviour then performed on the result of the cast operates as fast as if the type had originally been `T`.

Comment: @Tony D I understand the cast fully, and made only a small error that I acknowledged. Thank you anyway, I will rephrase the question in a minute.

Comment: @Tony D the point i was trying to make is that the only the array's types are known at compile time, not the arrays themselves (or their lengths as strings), despite const ref or whatever. I realise in hindsight it is kinda obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

Copying the array may be necessary to get a reference. I hope this answer will draw attention to the real subject of your question..

Calling foo with an appropriate-looking (and generic) cast looks as follows

```
reinterpret_cast<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(t[0])>::type [sizeof(t)-1]>(t+1)
```

but the above is invalid - you cannot cast const char* to const char[4]; Also you cannot obtain a reference in another way since an array cannot be copy constructed. So you may need to either copy or use std::array in c++11, which really boils down to having two template parameters.

Here is a valid solution however:

```
typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(t[0])>::type  element_type;
foo(reinterpret_cast<element_type(&) [sizeof(T)-1]>(t[1]));
```

Comment: Why is the reinterpret_cast from const char* to const char[4] invalid?   I thought there was an exception in the type aliasing rules for char.

Comment: @razeh wow a flaw in c's array typing - *incredible* - on the other it only requires a change from t+1 -> t[1] and char[4] -> char* is obviously valid.